# Private debian repository malformed Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, deb, gnupg, raspberrypi

I have a raspberry pi model 3. I am trying to create a .deb package for remotely updating the raspberry. The idea is that it is going to be distributed through an private remote repository.

the contents of my sources.list on the RB are:
`deb [arch=armhf] http://[ipadress]:80/ourrepo DistV1 main`

The contents of the DistV1 directory are:

```
4096  Nov 1   06:49 dev
1019  Nov 29 04:42 InRelease
4096  Nov 28 10:20 main
4096  Nov 28 07:18 old_releases
671    Nov 29 04:41 Release
299    Nov 29 04:41 Release.gpg
```

My InRelease File:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256
Origin: ourrepo
Label: ourrepo
Suite: DistV1
Codename: DistV1
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2017 09:59:00 UTC
Architectures: armhf
Components: main
Description: Repository for the our package
MD5Sum:
5da702a21ec9a83848abbe3e6cdf2047 374 main/binary-armhf/Packages
fc0b5fd48f308da66332befaa80de52d 113 main/binary-armhf/Release
SHA1:
fe6e3cae5ba8296f7d77269318ce97d2aae61e55 374 main/binary-armhf/Packages
9d70645b7e4029eb5061238f77271e6e08e968dd 113 main/binary-armhf/Release
SHA256:
555cd077b864ef7e6f02a71345ab68d4ba0eee2e738799ddac5b7ca01449721e 374 main/binary-armhf/Packages
76f25379fd22279b9f197aaaedc95f5d5fd828336c2bbbae5efeaff10f4f6422 113 main/binary-armhf/Release
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1

Signature

-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

The gpg key I used to sign the Release file on the remote server, is already added to the gpg ring on the RB.

---

When I use the sudo apt-get update, it hits the InRelease file but then:

```
Failed to fetch http://ipadress:80/package/dists/DistV1/InRelease Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' In Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

I fail to see what's causing this. Without the release files I can already update install and remove the package with apt-get so I think I can say for sure that the sources.list entry is valid.

What could be wrong with the InRelease file? What do I need for the entry `main/binary-armhf/Packages` to be found?

Thanks in advance! For missing information, just ask :)

Comment: But it doesnt explain what CAUSES the problem, sure malformed Release file. I don't have any explanation why the entry is not found though, so I am hoping to get a solution in that direction. As far as I know I followed all the steps, I dont see what I am missing

Comment: Noo sorry, really something different. Its our own private repository, and our own packages, im trying to get the info on what can cause the InRelease file to be malformed?